# Delete AVAsset Using Url

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I found many examples regarding deleting video from Photos app. But none of them seem to work. I want to know if i am doing something wrong? Here's the snippet -

```
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({

                let assetsToBeDeleted = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: ["video.mov"], options: nil) 

                PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(assetsToBeDeleted)
            }) { deleted, error in
                if deleted {
                    print("Deleted")


                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is i know something about `PHPhotoLibrary framework`.

Once you have saved any photos or videos in asset to the device `PHPhotoLibrary` your app is no longer the owner of that asset, so the device must ensure the app has the user's permission before it goes about deleting such data.

You can not delete from your app any photos or video without permission.

You need to store that `assets` URL in Database and then you can try this way.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges( {
    let imageAssetToDelete = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs(**imageUrl**, options: nil)
    PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(imageAssetToDelete)
},
    completionHandler: { success, error in
        NSLog("Finished deleting asset. %@", (success ? "Success" : error))
})
```

Comment: WhatsApp is doing it, for example. It deletes photos from your Photos app if you decided to synchronize the galleries.

Comment: you can delete that photos or video but need to store assets url in your DB or Local.

Comment: That's fine. You didn't add the code when I commented :)

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti, i approached this way also but it didn't work.Video stays where it was stored. AssetUrl means the URL it was exported to right ?

Comment: URL is form original image while add to PHPhotoLibrary.

Comment: I actually didn't get you. I posted nearly the same code like in the answer and also printed url at both places. Both url are same but not deleting the video.